# Debugging on MVC3 solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, firebug

This is an MVC3 project, when I run the solution and investigate the process flows thru firebug, there is a list of repeative url (pls see the red box).

[image]

I am confused, what does the repetative lines mean? At first, I suspect that the same controller + action being called many times, but after debugging, seems that the controller only being called once.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please add relevant tags to your question? I don't see what this has to do with the C language.

Comment: Please show the javascript code that is injecting those CSS tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is a firebug thing. It most likely means you have multiple inline css stiles and it lists them so you can navigate straight to them by clicking in the menu.